# make custom number pad class called by several view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls

I'm new to objective-c and iOS programming.I want to use a custom number pad for a game input. There are several types of games, (game1 game2 game3) and the games may require more or less numbers to be displayed on the number pad (control).
Each games rules and display properties are written in separate view controller classes. I tried cutting and pasting a copy of the number pad from game1 to the other controllers. It throws an error (at build), saying the name for the number buttons properties that I am using have already been used.

Will this would require me to rename and relink all object and properties for each game. To much maintenance overhead for me. So I have been trying to make a NumPad class, derived from `NSObject`.
This works fine until I try to create a view/container view from the non view controller class. I instantiate the numpad object in the viewdidload section of the game1 view controller. This is what I have so far.

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NumberPadTestAppDelegate.h"

@interface NumPad : NSObject


-(void)numberPadSetUp: (int) numberOfButtons;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "NumPad.h"

@implementation NumPad

-(void)numberPadSetUp: (int) numberOfButtons
{
      // Instantiate a Container View by code??? test.
   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(14, 47, 740, 370);
   UIView *Mycontainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
   Mycontainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   [Mycontainer addSubview:Mycontainer];

      // This was here for testing before adding the above four lines.
   for (int a = 1; a < numberOfButtons +1; a++)
        {
        NSLog(@"Button %i has been added.",a);
        }
   NSLog(@"  ");
   NSLog(@"Numberpad setup is complete.");
} // End of "numberPadSetUp" routine.

@end
```

.m file from game1 test controller

```
#import "NumberPadTestViewController.h"

@interface NumberPadTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation NumberPadTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   NumPad *MyNumberPad =[[NumPad alloc]init];

   [MyNumberPad numberPadSetUp:9];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This code gives a run time error as written.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([NumberPadTestAppDelegate class]));
   }
}
```

I was also wondering if using the container view control in IB would accomplish the task or might I get the same naming errors as before? 
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in this line

```
[Mycontainer addSubview:Mycontainer];
```

You are declaring `Mycontainer` and adding it to itself. You should write class like follow

```
#import "NumPad.h"

@implementation NumPad

#define kButtonWidth 50
#define kButtonHeight 15
#define kPadding 20

-(void)numberPadSetUp: (int) numberOfButtons
{
    // Instantiate a Container View by code??? test.
    // This was here for testing before adding the above four lines.
    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a < numberOfButtons +1; a++)
    {
        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        CGRect aButtonFrame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, kButtonWidth, kButtonHeight);
        aButton.frame = aButtonFrame;
        [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",a] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:aButton];

        xPos+=kButtonWidth+kPadding;

        if(fmod(a, 3)==0){
            yPos+=kButtonHeight+kPadding;
            xPos = 0;
        }


        NSLog(@"Button %i has been added.",a);
    }
    NSLog(@"  ");
    NSLog(@"Numberpad setup is complete.");
} // End of "numberPadSetUp" routine.


@end
```

And in your main class

```
NumPad *MyNumberPad =[[NumPad alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 47, 740, 370)];
[MyNumberPad numberPadSetUp:9];
[self.view addSubview:MyNumberPad];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:MyNumberPad];
```

This will give you result like following images in iOS6/iOS7

[image: iOS6] [image: iOS7]

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the correct direction. Your code still gave me an error, but I found it was on my end. I changed my class NumPad to derived from NSObject to UIView and then was able to achieve what I was after. Thanks again for your help.